# ASP .NET Core 2 Can not add bower.json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bower

I have a problem adding bower.json to my solution.

There is no bower configuration file in items to add, and bower-init does not work either. How can I add bower.json to my project?

Comment: looks like bower is not more supported see https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower

Comment: there is bower.json item in the screenshot,  but my visual studio 2017 community with everything installed properly does not have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this for me was to manually add bower.json and bowerrc.